# apply jq filter on sub level only, keeping the rest of the JSON intact

Tags: json, jq, flatten

Given a nested object, is it possible to only apply a filter to a sub level of the json and then have as output the original json which includes the sub level to which one has applied the filter?

So for instance if I have a json like this:

```
{"k1": "v1",
 "k2": "v2",
 "k3": "v3",
 "k4": [],
 "records": [{
        "kk1": "vv1",
        "kk2": ["vv2"],
        "releases": [{"kkk1":"vvv1"}, 
                     {"parties":[{"name":"value",
                                  "kkkk1":"value"}, 
                                 {"name":"value",
                                  "kkkk1":"value"}]}],
        "kk4": "vv4",

        "kk5": "vv5"},
        {
        "kk1": "o_vv1",
        "kk2": ["o_vv2"],
        "releases": [{"kkk1":"o_vvv1"}, 
                     {"parties":[{"name":"o_value",
                                  "kkkk1":"o_value"}, 
                                {"name":"o_value",
                                 "kkkk1":"o_value"}]}],
        "kk4": "o_vv4",

        "kk5": "o_vv5"}],
 "k6":"v6"}
```

I would like as output this same json, but with the nested objects in `.[].records[].releases[].parties` flattened, so the desired output should be:

```
previous keys
...
 "records": [{
        "kk1": "vv1",
        "kk2": ["vv2"],
        "releases": [{"kkk1":"vvv1"}, 
                     {"parties.0.name":"value",
                      "parties.0.kkkk1":"value", 
                      "parties.1.name":"value",
                      "parties.1.kkkk1": "value"}]
       "kk4": "vv4",
       "kk5": "vv5"}, 
       {
       "kk1": "other_vv1",
       "kk2": ["other_vv2"],
       "releases": [{"kkk1":"vvv1"}, 
                    {"parties.0.name":"value",
                     "parties.0.kkkk1":"value", 
                     "parties.1.name":"value",
                     "parties.1.kkkk1": "value"}]
       "kk4": "other_vv4",
       "kk5": "other_vv5"},
...
following keys
```

Edit:
 the current jq command :

```
 jq '.[].records[].releases[].parties| . as $ho | reduce paths(scalars) as $path ({}; . + {($path | map(tostring) | join(".")): $ho | getpath($path)})'
```

Comment: Your sample input doesn't match the actual data you posted; a working solution for your sample might not work for your actual input, and vice versa. Please fix it and let us know, also see [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to replace only a sub part you can use `|=`  instead of `|` , just after `.parties`

So i think this will achieve your goal :

```
.[].records[].releases[].parties |= 
  (. as $ho 
   | reduce paths(scalars) as $path ({};
       . + {($path | map(tostring) | join(".")):
             $ho | getpath($path)}))
```